# Is it bad to run a long-running process on a server in a Gnu Screen session?

Tags: cron, gnu-screen, long-running-processes

I have a long running process that currently logs output to stderr, and I'm just starting it up and leaving it running on the server within a gnu screen session on the server, which I just detach when I logout of the server and reattach after I log in, if I want to see what the process is doing.

Are there any drawbacks to running a long-running process this way?

Comment: Sounds fine to me, but this question is probably best suited for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screen is designed for this.  So no, there are no real drawbacks this way.